# jquery not working on button click i dont know why

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a form

```
<form method="POST" action="">
  <div class="commentdiv">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" class="id" value="<?php echo $pixid;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="username" id="username" value="<?php echo $activeusername;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="uid" id="uid" value="<?php echo $id3;?>">
    <textarea style="" name="comment" id="comment" class="comment" placeholder="  comment here"></textarea>
    <button type="button" style="background-color: Transparent; background-repeat:no-repeat; border: none; cursor:pointer; overflow: hidden; color: #3897f0; font-weight:600;"class="submit">
      comment
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

and this is my javascript

```
$(document).on('click', '.submit', function () {

    $post = $(this);
    var username2 = $(this).parent().find("#username").val();
    var comment2 = $(this).parent().find("#comment").val();

    $commentsec = $(this).closest("form").next(".comments");

    //Get values of input fields from DOM structure 
    var dataString = {
        id: $(this).parent().find("#id").val(),
        username: $(this).parent().find("#username").val(),
        uid: $(this).parent().find("#uid").val(),
        comment: $(this).parent().find("#comment").val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: 'comments.php',
        data: dataString,
        success: function () {
            alert("alert");
            $commentsec.append('<p class="written"><a href="users.php?id= <?php echo $id3 ?>"><b>' + username2 + '</b> </a>' + comment2 + "</p>" + '<div class="dropdown"><img src="ellipsis.png" class="dots"><div class="dropdown-content"><br><p  class="delete" data-delete=<?php echo $commentid; ?>">delete</p></div></div>');
            $(" #comment").val("");
        }
    });
});
```

i want that whenever a user clicks on this button 
an alert should pop up and that comment should append to this form that user has written this code used to work fine but now i dont know what happened it suddenly stopped working can you guys help me rest of my jquery code is working instead of this code

Comment: Did you tried `data: JSON.stringify({ dataString })` in AJAX? Look into console and let us know what the issue showing?

Comment: nope this code worked fine but dont know what happened suddenly @JitendraRangpariya

Comment: Did you mean, you are not getting even click event occurring on button?

Comment: yes  @PrasadWargad

Comment: code seems to be ok. The problem could be in your ajax call: go to the chrome debugging tool and check your "Network" tab (filter by XHR) and look on comments.php status

Comment: You can also use console tab in inspect element of the browser. There you can see errors too.

Comment: where is your comments class? is it comment or comments class in next()?

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$('.submit').click(function () {
  $post = $(this);
  var username2 = $(this).parent().find("#username").val();
  var comment2 = $(this).parent().find("#comment").val();
  $commentsec = $(this).closest("form").find(".comment"); // here you missed to get comment element too.
  var dataString = {
      id: $(this).parent().find("#id").val(),
      username: $(this).parent().find("#username").val(),
      uid: $(this).parent().find("#uid").val(),
      comment: $(this).parent().find("#comment").val()
  };
  // remaining printing stuff goes here
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('click', '.submit', function () {

    $post = $(this);
    var username2 = $(this).parent().find("#username").val();
    var comment2 = $(this).parent().find("#comment").val();

    $commentsec = $(this).closest("form").next(".comments");

    //Get values of input fields from DOM structure 
    var dataString = {
        id: $(this).parent().find("#id").val(),
        username: $(this).parent().find("#username").val(),
        uid: $(this).parent().find("#uid").val(),
        comment: $(this).parent().find("#comment").val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: 'comments.php',
        data: dataString,
        method: "POST",
        success: function () {
            alert("alert");
            $commentsec.append('<p class="written"><a href="users.php?id= <?php echo $id3 ?>"><b>' + username2 + '</b> </a>' + comment2 + "</p>" + '<div class="dropdown"><img src="ellipsis.png" class="dots"><div class="dropdown-content"><br><p  class="delete" data-delete=<?php echo $commentid; ?>">delete</p></div></div>');
            $(" #comment").val("");
        },
        error:function(err){
        console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" action="">
  <div class="commentdiv">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" class="id" value="<?php echo $pixid;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="username" id="username" value="<?php echo $activeusername;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="uid" id="uid" value="<?php echo $id3;?>">
    <textarea style="" name="comment" id="comment" class="comment" placeholder="  comment here"></textarea>
    <button type="button" style="background-color: Transparent; background-repeat:no-repeat; border: none; cursor:pointer; overflow: hidden; color: #3897f0; font-weight:600;"class="submit">
      comment
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

You should add method in ajax configuration.

Answer (score -1):

```js
 $(document).on('click', '.submit', function () {

    $post = $(this);
    var username2 = $(this).parent().find("#username").val();
    var comment2 = $(this).parent().find("#comment").val();

    $commentsec = $(this).closest("form").next(".comments");

    //Get values of input fields from DOM structure 
    var dataString = {
        id: $(this).parent().find("#id").val(),
        username: $(this).parent().find("#username").val(),
        uid: $(this).parent().find("#uid").val(),
        comment: $(this).parent().find("#comment").val()
    };
    //your ajax request here
    console.log(dataString)
});
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="">
  <div class="commentdiv">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" class="id" value="<?php echo $pixid;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="username" id="username" value="<?php echo $activeusername;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="uid" id="uid" value="<?php echo $id3;?>">
    <textarea style="" name="comment" id="comment" class="comment" placeholder="  comment here"></textarea>
    <button type="button" class="submit">
      comment
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i think my ajax is bringing me problems

Comment: Your ajax request missing type. Add   type: "POST"

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).on('click','.submit',function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $post = $(this);
    var username2 = $(this).parent().find("#username").val();
    var comment2 = $(this).parent().find("#comment").val();

    $commentsec = $(this).closest("form").next(".comments");

    //Get values of input fields from DOM structure 
    var dataString = {
        id: $(this).parent().find("#id").val(),
        username: $(this).parent().find("#username").val(),
        uid: $(this).parent().find("#uid").val(),
        comment: $(this).parent().find("#comment").val()
    };
   //Get values of input fields from DOM structure 
   var dataString = {
        id: $(this).parent().find("#id").val(),
        username: $(this).parent().find("#username").val(),
        uid: $(this).parent().find("#uid").val(),
         comment: $(this).parent().find("#comment").val()
    };

   $.ajax({
   url:'comments.php',  
   data:dataString,
   success:function(){
 $commentsec.append('<p class="written"><a href="users.php?id= <?php echo $id3; ?>"><b>'+username2+'</b> </a>'+comment2+"</p>"+'<div class="dropdown"><img src="ellipsis.png" class="dots"><div class="dropdown-content"><br><p  class="delete" data-delete=<?php echo $commentid; ?>">delete</p></div></div>');
     $(" #comment").val("");   
   }
   });
});
```

this code worked for me i dont know how